# Concatenating Pandas dataframes, getting Nan values for first dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to join two dataframes. 'df' is my initial dataframe containing all the header information I require. 'row' is my first row of data that I want to append to 'df'.

```
df =
   FName E1         E2          E3          E4          E5          E6
0  Nan   2          2           2           2           2           2
1  Nan   1          1           1           1           1           1
2  Nan   3          4           5           6           7           8
3  Nan   4          5           6           7           8           10
4  Nan   1002003004 1002004005  1002005006  1002006007  1002007008  1002008010


row =
   0                                        1       2       3       4       5       6
0  501#_ZMB_2019-04-03_070528_reciprocals   30.0193 30.0193 30.0193 34.8858 34.8858 34.8858
```

I'm trying to create this:

```
   FName                                    E1          E2          E3          E4          E5          E6
0  Nan                                      2           2           2           2           2           2
1  Nan                                      1           1           1           1           1           1
2  Nan                                      3           4           5           6           7           8
3  Nan                                      4           5           6           7           8           10
4  Nan                                      1002003004  1002004005  1002005006  1002006007  1002007008  1002008010
5  501#_ZMB_2019-04-03_070528_reciprocals   30.0193     30.0193     30.0193     34.8858     34.8858     34.8858
```

I have tried the following:

```
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

and

```
df = pd.concat([df, row], ignore_index=True)
```

Both of these result in the loss of all the data in the first df, which should contain all the header information.

```
   0                                        1       2       3       4       5       6
0  Nan                                      Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan
1  Nan                                      Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan
2  Nan                                      Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan
3  Nan                                      Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan
4  Nan                                      Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan
5  501#_ZMB_2019-04-03_070528_reciprocals   30.0193 30.0193 30.0193 34.8858 34.8858 34.8858
```

I've also tried

```
df = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True), row.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)])
```

Which produced the following Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-146-3c1ecbd1987c>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True), row.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)])

  File "C:\Users\russells\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 228, in concat
    copy=copy, sort=sort)

  File "C:\Users\russells\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 280, in __init__
    raise ValueError('All objects passed were None')

ValueError: All objects passed were None
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a copy-pasteable version of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate extra rows, `pandas` aligns the columns, which currently do not overlap. `rename` will get the job done:

```
pd.concat([df, row.rename(columns=dict(zip(row.columns, df.columns)))],
           ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
                                    FName          E1          E2          E3          E4          E5          E6
0                                     Nan           2           2           2           2           2           2
1                                     Nan           1           1           1           1           1           1
2                                     Nan           3           4           5           6           7           8
3                                     Nan           4           5           6           7           8          10
4                                     Nan  1002003004  1002004005  1002005006  1002006007  1002007008  1002008010
5  501#_ZMB_2019-04-03_070528_reciprocals     30.0193     30.0193     30.0193     34.8858     34.8858     34.8858
```

---

Or if you just need to assign one row at the end and you have a `RangeIndex` on `df`:

```
df.loc[df.shape[0], :] = row.to_numpy()
```